# How should format my scss class names to achieve this effect?

Tags: css, sass, bem

I am trying to create a slide in sidebar effect.

Using `scss` I have given my sidebar a width and then offset it to the right by that width.

I'd like to then apply `sidebar--is-open` class and have the sidebar appear.

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #444444; 

  &--open {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

I am expecting this state

```
<div class="sidebar">
...
</div>
```

To change to this

```
<div class="sidebar sidebar--is-open">
...
</div>
```

But nothing is happening in the dev tools.

I can see the new class is applied, but the css does not take effect not does it appear the class has any css against it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `is-` part in your `SCSS`.

Comment: oh my god hahaha, thank you so much. I was staring at that for so long too, wow. thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome! :)